# How do I kill all processes running from a particular directory?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, kill

I'm looking for a quick terminal command that will kill all of the processes which are running from a particular directory (or a subdirectory of that directory).

For example, let's say I have the `bin1` and `bin2` executables running. They live at the following paths:

`/path/to/processes/subdir1/bin1`

`/path/to/processes/subdir2/subsubdir2/bin2`

I want to kill both bin1 and bin2 by only specifying `/path/to/processes` such that the command will find and kill both `bin1` and `bin2` because of their location.

Answer (score 4):

Old question I know but I came across this looking for an answer and eventually found one. I don't know if this is the "best" way to do this or not but you gotta start somewhere and I've found this to be very reliable:

```sh
ps -eo pid | while read line; do pwdx $line 2> /dev/null; done | grep "your/path/here" | cut -d':' -f1 | while read line; do kill $line; done;
```

- `ps -eo pid`: lists all process ids
- `while read line; do pwdx $line 2> /dev/null; done`: gets more info about each process, including the directory it's running from
- `2> /dev/null`: removes error lines about processes you don't have permissions to (optional)
- `cut -d':' -f1` extracts only the pids
- `while read line; do kill $line; done;`: kills each process by pid

Answer (score 1):

I use this command to kill process in a specific directory:

```
lsof | grep '\/path\/to\/processes\/' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to say:

```
ps --no-headers axk comm o pid,args | awk '$2 ~ "/path/to/processes/"{print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```